# How do you make DBMS_DATAPUMP error if there's an error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

DBMS_DATAPUMP doesn't fail when the columns in the source and destination tables do not match. This means that no exceptions are raised. I'm trying to use the GET_STATUS procedure in order to understand if there are any errors but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be...

My ultimate goal is for DBMS_DATAPUMP to raise an exception if the import fails. Differing columns is an easy example to work with as I know that it should fail.

Here's my current code (I've obscured schema names purposefully). The environment I'm using is identical on both servers save that I've added an extra column to the source table. I also perform a count of the number of rows in the table.

```
connect schema/*@db1/db1
-- */

create table tmp_test_datapump as
 select u.*, cast(null as number) as break_it
   from user_tables u;

Table created.


select count(*) from tmp_test_datapump;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1170

connect schema/*@db2/db2
-- */

set serveroutput on

create table tmp_test_datapump as
 select u.*
   from user_tables u;

Table created.
```

In attempting to test this the DATAPUMP code has got a little more complicated. Everything in the infinite loop can be removed and this would act the same.

```
declare
   l_handle number;
   l_status varchar2(255);
   l_job_state varchar2(4000);
   l_ku$status ku$_status1020;
begin
   l_handle := dbms_datapump.open( operation => 'IMPORT'
                                 , job_mode => 'TABLE'
                                 , remote_link => 'SCHEMA.DB.DOMAIN.COM'
                                 , job_name => 'JOB_TEST_DP'
                                 , version => 'COMPATIBLE' );
   dbms_datapump.set_parameter( handle => l_handle
                              , name => 'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION'
                              , value => 'TRUNCATE');
   dbms_datapump.metadata_filter( handle => l_handle
                                , name => 'NAME_EXPR'
                                , value => 'IN (''TMP_TEST_DATAPUMP'')');
   dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => l_handle);

   while true loop
      dbms_datapump.wait_for_job(handle => l_handle,job_state => l_status);

      if l_status in ('COMPLETED','STOPPED') then
         exit;
      end if;

      dbms_datapump.get_status( handle => l_handle
                              , mask => dbms_datapump.KU$_STATUS_JOB_ERROR
                              , job_state => l_job_state
                              , status => l_ku$status);
      dbms_output.put_line('state: ' || l_job_state);
      if l_ku$status.error is not null and l_ku$status.error.count > 0 then

         for i in l_ku$status.error.first .. l_ku$status.error.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(l_ku$status.error(i).logtext);
         end loop;
       end if;
   end loop;

end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select count(*) from tmp_test_datapump;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        47
```

As you can see the number of records in the tables is different; the import has failed and no exception has been raised. [Various](http://danirey.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/the-gains-and-pains-of-dbms_datapump-part-i/) [blogs](http://dbaharrison.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/dbmsdatapump-finding-out-what-actual.html) and [DBA.SE questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72575/oracle-dbms-datapump-removes-dumpfile-after-succesful-import) imply that some sort of error catching can be done; but I can't seem to manage it.

How can you catch fatal errors in a DBMS_DATAPUMP import?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with `dbms_datapump` package right know. The following procedure is searching one table for schemas that will be exported. `BACKUP_INFO_MOD` is a procedure with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION` that's making logs in another table.
Example 6.3 from [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#i1008408) helped me a lot. Here's fragment from my code (with additional commentary):

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BACKUP_EXECUTE (
    threads in number := 1 
  , dir in varchar2 := 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'
  ) AS 
    schemas varchar2(255);
    filename varchar2(255);
    path varchar2(255);
    errormsg varchar2(4000);

    handle number;
    job_state varchar2(30);
    --variables under this line are important to error handling
    logs ku$_LogEntry;
    lindx pls_integer;
    status ku$_Status;

    exporterr exception; --our exception to handle export errors

    [...]
  BEGIN    
    [...]
        schemas:=schema_list(indx).schema_name;

        --Full dir path for logs
        select directory_path into path from dba_directories where directory_name=dir;
        --If data not found then automatically raise NO_DATA_FOUND

        select to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDDHH24MI-')||lower(schemas)||'.dmp' into filename from dual;

        backup_info_mod('insert',path||filename,schemas);

        begin --For inner exception handling on short fragment
          handle := dbms_datapump.open('EXPORT','SCHEMA');
          dbms_datapump.add_file(handle, filename, dir); --dump file
          dbms_datapump.add_file(handle, filename||'.log', dir,null,DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE); --export log file
          dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle, 'SCHEMA_EXPR', 'IN ('''||schemas||''')');
          dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle,threads);

          backup_info_mod(file_name=>path||filename, curr_status=>'IN PROGRESS');

          dbms_datapump.start_job(handle);

        --If job didn't start due to some errors, then let's get some information
        exception
          when others then
            dbms_datapump.get_status(handle,8,0,job_state,status);
        --This will overwrite our job_state and status
        end;

        --Let's go handle error if job_state was overwritten
        if job_state is not null then
          raise exporterr;
        else
          job_state:='UNDEFINED';
        end if;

        --Checking in loop if errors occurred. I'm not using wait_for_job
        --because it didn't work out
        while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop
        --Like before, let's get some information
          dbms_datapump.get_status(handle,8,-1,job_state,status);

        --Looking for errors using mask
          if (bitand(status.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0) then          
        --If occurred: let's stop the export job and raise an error
            dbms_datapump.stop_job(handle);
            dbms_datapump.detach(handle);
            raise exporterr;
          exit;

          end if;
        end loop;

        backup_info_mod(file_name=>path||filename, curr_status=>'COMPLETED');

        dbms_datapump.detach(handle);

      exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
          backup_info_mod('insert',null,schemas,'ERROR','No '||dir||' defined in dba_directories');

        when exporterr then
        --Let's get all error messages and write it to errormsg variable
          logs:=status.error;
          lindx:=logs.FIRST;

          while lindx is not null loop
            errormsg:=errormsg||logs(lindx).LogText;
            lindx:=logs.NEXT(lindx);

            if lindx is not null then
              errormsg:=errormsg||' | '; --Just to separate error messages
            end if;
          end loop;

          backup_info_mod(
            file_name=>path||filename,
            curr_status=>'ERROR',
            errormsg=>errormsg);

        /*when other then --TODO
          null;
          */
      end;

  END BACKUP_EXECUTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the datapump command in a shell script when the log is created for the impdp, and before you end the shell script you can check the log for IMP- errors or ORA- errors, if true warn the user to look at the log file for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this isn't really helpful. I'm not going to call shell scripts from within the database if it's avoidable and it makes it a lot more difficult to automate.

Answer (score 0):

The provided [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL977) from yammy is good.

I faced the same problem when using the dbms_datapump package to import a DB dump. Even there are error during the import, the job is treated as success / finished. By using the code example in the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL977), i could get the error / log message during the import. I then check if there are 'ORA-' found in the log message and throw a custom error when the import job is finished.

Following is the sample code:

```
PROMPT CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import_schema

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import_db_dump (
    dumpFilename        IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    handle NUMBER;              -- Handler of the job
    loopIdx NUMBER;             -- Loop index
    percentDone NUMBER;         -- Percentage of job complete
    jobState VARCHAR2(30);      -- To keep track of job state
    ku_logEntry ku$_LogEntry;   -- For WIP and error messages
    ku_jobStatus ku$_JobStatus; -- The job status from get_status
    ku_jobDescjd ku$_JobDesc;   -- The job description from get_status
    ku_Status ku$_Status;       -- The status object returned by get_status

    errorCount          NUMBER;
    import_error_found  EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
    handle := dbms_datapump.open (
    operation =>    'IMPORT',
    job_mode =>     'SCHEMA');

    dbms_output.put_line('Define table exists action: truncate');
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter (
        handle =>   handle,
        name =>     'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION',
        value =>    'TRUNCATE');

    dbms_output.put_line('Define dumpfilename: ' || dumpFilename);
    dbms_datapump.add_file (
        handle =>       handle,
        filename =>     dumpFilename,
        filetype =>     dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);

    dbms_output.put_line('Start datapump job');
    dbms_output.put_line('==================');
    dbms_datapump.start_job (handle);

    -- Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL977

    -- The import job should now be running. In the following loop, the job is
    -- monitored until it completes. In the meantime, progress information is
    -- displayed.

    percentDone := 0;
    jobState := 'UNDEFINED';
    errorCount := 0;
    WHILE (jobState != 'COMPLETED') AND (jobState != 'STOPPED') LOOP
        dbms_datapump.get_status(handle,
               dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
               dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
               dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,
               -1, jobState, ku_Status);
        ku_jobStatus := ku_Status.job_status;

        -- If the percentage done changed, display the new value.
        IF ku_jobStatus.percent_done != percentDone THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('*** Job percent done = ' ||
                               to_char(ku_jobStatus.percent_done));
          percentDone := ku_jobStatus.percent_done;
        END IF;

        -- If any work-in-progress (WIP) or Error messages were received for the job,
        -- display them.

        IF (bitand(ku_Status.mask, dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0) THEN
            ku_logEntry := ku_Status.wip;
        ELSE
            IF (bitand(ku_Status.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0) THEN
                ku_logEntry := ku_Status.error;
            ELSE
                ku_logEntry := null;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF ku_logEntry IS NOT NULL THEN
            loopIdx := ku_logEntry.FIRST;
            WHILE loopIdx IS NOT NULL LOOP
                dbms_output.put_line(ku_logEntry(loopIdx).LogText);
                IF INSTR(ku_logEntry(loopIdx).LogText, 'ORA-') > 0 THEN
                    errorCount := errorCount + 1;
                    dbms_output.put_line('^^^^---ERROR FOUND');
                END IF;
                loopIdx := ku_logEntry.NEXT(loopIdx);
            END LOOP;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    -- Indicate that the job finished and gracefully detach from it.
    dbms_output.put_line('Job has completed');
    dbms_output.put_line('Final job state = ' || jobState);
    dbms_datapump.detach(handle);

    IF errorCount > 0 THEN
        RAISE import_error_found;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN import_error_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error found when import. Number of error: ' || errorCount);
        RAISE;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('[Error Backtrace]');
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
        dbms_output.put_line('[Call Stack]');
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_call_stack());

        dbms_datapump.stop_job(handle);
        RAISE;
END;
/
```

Hope this help.